# Cannot connect to Polarion service via WebServiceFactory

Tags: java, eclipse, polarion

i'am trying to connect to Polarion with the WebServiceFactory using Java. But a NoClassDefFoundError - Exception gets thrown. I found nothing helpful in google :(

```
    serverUrl = "http://.../polarion/ws/services/";
    WebServiceFactory factory = new WebServiceFactory(serverUrl);
```

Error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
at org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory.class$(LogFactory.java:45)
at org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory$1.run(LogFactory.java:45)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory.getLogFactory(LogFactory.java:41)
at org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory.<clinit>(LogFactory.java:33)
at org.apache.axis.handlers.BasicHandler.<clinit>(BasicHandler.java:43)
at org.apache.axis.client.Service.getAxisClient(Service.java:104)
at org.apache.axis.client.Service.<init>(Service.java:113)
at com.polarion.alm.ws.client.tracker.TrackerWebServiceServiceLocator.<init>(TrackerWebServiceServiceLocator.java:16)
at com.polarion.alm.ws.client.WebServiceFactory.<init>(WebServiceFactory.java:78)
at sesa.polarion.connection.PolarionConnectionImpl.<init>(PolarionConnectionImpl.java:92)
at sesa.XmlPolarionCon.main.Main.main(Main.java:28)
```

**EDIT:**

I found out that this may be a Problem with Java-Libraries (in Eclipse). The imported jar library isn't working properly and the icon looks unusual. Like normal jar-Icon with a sheet in bottom left corner (i hope you can somewhat imagine what I mean). What does this mean?

Sadly I can't post images because of my reputation :(

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all that have the same problem.
I solved the problem by reimporting **all** libraries!

Answer (score 0):

Import all the supporting libs from Polarion-HOME\SDK\lib\com.polarion.alm.ws.client\lib.

This would solve the problem